# Python Transparent KivyMD Navigation Drawer

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to apply some changes to my app (digital planner), one of which is being able to switch screens within *MDNavigationDrawer*, but I have two problems:

1. The nav. drawer is transparent. I tried setting its opacity equal to 1 - didn't work.
2. The nav. drawer seems to be "under" the screen. If positions of a button on the nav. drawer and a button on the screen match, button being pressed is the one that's one the screen, not the one that's on the nav. drawer.

**Here's what the MDNavigationDrawer looks like**

[image]

Here's a bit of my Kivy code:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    manager: manager
    nav_drawer: nav_drawer

    MDToolbar:
        id: tb
        type: "top"
        title: "VPlanner"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
        right_action_items: [["settings", lambda x: app.open_settings()]]

    NavigationLayout:
        x: tb.height
    
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:    

        ScreenManager:
            id: manager

            menu_window: menu_window
            stats_window: stats_window
            history_window: history_window

            MenuWindow:
                id: menu_window

            StatsWindow:
                id: stats_window

            HistoryWindow:
                id: history_window


<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    cols: 1
    orientation: "vertical"

    OneLineListItem:
        text: "Menu"

        size_hint: 1, None
        on_release: 
            app.root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
            app.root.manager.current = "menu"

    OneLineListItem:
        text: "Statistics"

        size_hint: 1, None
        on_release: 
            app.root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
            app.root.manager.current = "stats"

    OneLineListItem:
        text: "History"

        size_hint: 1, None
        on_release: 
            app.root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
            app.root.manager.current = "history"
```

And here's a tiny bit of my Python code:

```
# there were lots of lines in each class representing screens,
# so I only left the ContentNavigationDrawer class, which is,
# as you already figured it out, supposed to represent content
# displayed in the MDNavigationDrawer.


class ContentNavigationDrawer(GridLayout):
    pass
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The Navigation Drawer appears transparent because it was placed before the *ScreenManager*.

## Solution

Place *MDNavigationDrawer:* after *ScreenManager:*

### Snippets

```
NavigationLayout:
    x: tb.height

    ScreenManager:
        id: manager

        ...
        HistoryWindow:
            id: history_window

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer

        ContentNavigationDrawer:
```

## Output

[image: KivyMD MDNavigationDrawer]