# discord.py Pillow train meme command text overlapping

Tags: python, discord, python-imaging-library

So whenever I try to do this command, It works successfully but the text overlays instead of pasting the empty train meme template over it

```
@client.command()
async def trainmeme(ctx, *, text):
  text = text.split(",")
  text2 = text[0]
  text3 = text[1]
  img = Image.open("train.jpg")
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
  drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
  font = ImageFont.truetype("Arimo.ttf", 50)
  drawer.text((197, 165), text=text2, font=font)
  draw.text((87, 531), text=text3, font=font)
  img.save("train.jpg")
  img.paste(img, (7, 5))
  await ctx.send(file = discord.File("train.jpg"))
```

Here is a picture of what happens when I try to do the command multiple times
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197440/python-transparent-kivymd-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `img.save("train.jpg")` which overwrites the original image file.